# Как сделать, чтобы определенный блок кода выполнился после загрузки страницы и после выполнения всех скриптов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте. Как сделать, чтобы определенный блок кода выполнился после загрузки страницы и после выполнения всех скриптов?

Comment: А если таких блоков - два?

Comment: Я сам буду назначать это.

Answer (score 0):

Единственный надёжный способ - [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: у меня оно даже не вызывается

Answer (score 0):

В jquery вроде так можно сделать

```
$(function() {

    // Ваш код

});
```